# Magento2 - Add custom attribute in transactional sales e-mail

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, transactional-mail

we are using magento 2.1.9ce.

In the ordermails are now (by default shown) the name, sku, qty, price and the size attribute.

Now I would like to add a custom attribute to this.
The name of the attribute is 'artikelnummer'.
But only the parent product has this attribute.

How can I add this to the transactional e-mail? So it reads this attribute from the parent product

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by observer for event `email_order_set_template_vars_before` which has `sender` and `transport` which is instance of `Magento\Framework\DataObject`.

In your observer find your attribute and then set it to transport by `->setData()` method

Comment: Thats sounds complicated .... I can do Some html and understand little php. Is that easy to do?

Comment: Here is tutorial how to create observer in Magento
https://webkul.com/blog/observers-in-magento2/

in events.xml just put event name `email_order_set_template_vars_before ` and the in execute() method something like:

`$transport = $observer->getTransport();
if(null !== $transport) {
//Add here your code to get your custom attribute
}`